# node.js -> res.sendFile() is not defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I am using node.js with mySQL. When I start the server, everything is ok, but when I access 127.0.0.1:3000, it says res.sendFile() is not defined. I want to send the index html file as a response from the server but it doesn't work. What is the problem?

```
var app = require('express')();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "127.0.0.1",
    user : "root",
    password : "",
    database : "user_data",
    port : 3306
});

db.connect();

app.get('/',function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: try res.json('hello') ; tell me what you see?

Comment: I see "hello" :)

Comment: What version of express?

Comment: sendFile is with every version

Comment: `res.sendFile()` is supported by Express v4.8.0 onwards.

Comment: What version of Express are you using?  The only reasons that `res.sendFile()` would not be there would be that `res` is wrong or this is an older version of Express.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, that feature(function) is not provisioned.

Sanitize your packages, first change **express** version to `4.15.2` then, delete your node_modules folder. Then `npm install`.

You should enable static file serving.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Then after words you can thus use res.reder('index');
Though you must set the view engine first.Here is little more information.

**app.render(view)**

Returns the rendered HTML of a view via the callback function. It accepts an optional parameter that is an object containing local variables for the view. It is like res.render(), except it cannot send the rendered view to the client on its own.

To setup your view engine follow this,

```
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: try a absolute path

Comment: that should provide you with the latest version of express, as mentioned by @4castle , the sendFile is only supported from version 4

Comment: you also should use static files.

Comment: What you are saying in your first paragraph does not match the error they are getting.  They aren't getting an error because `res.sendFile()` can't find the file, they are getting an error that the `.sendFile()` method is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a static file, you can also just do;

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
//public being the folder containing your index.html.

//Example of Path;
//__dirname + '/../public'
__dirname = start in same folder as server.js.
/../ = go one folder back (in this case, to ROOT.
/public = enter the "public" folder, this is where our index.html is.

ROOT
  Server
    server.js
  Public
    css
    images
    index.html
    etc
```

Comment: it have worked perfectly fine for me the last year's time. 
updated witth path explaination.